# Spark write to Ignite on Ignite custom schema

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I use Spark 2.3.0 and Ignite 2.7.0, I have created custom schemas in Ignite using

```
<property name="sqlSchemas">
        <list>
            <value>dbsch</value>
            <value>dbschma</value>
            <value>db_ui</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

I could create tables on each of the schema. But my problem is I cannot load data into the particular schema.

```
df.write
          .format(FORMAT_IGNITE)
          .option(OPTION_CONFIG_FILE, CONFIG)
          .option(OPTION_TABLE, "db_ui."+tableName)
          .option(OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS, primaryKey)
          .option(OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PARAMETERS, "template=replicated")
          .mode(SaveMode.Append)
          .save()
```

It tries to create table as the df and eventually fails by saying null in Spark Config. It works if I try to load the table in the public(default) schema. I get the same error if I try to read from Ignite. Any input please?

Ash

Comment: Any chance it has something to do with upper-casing that SQL usually does? Try to write the schema names in upper case (both in the config and in the DF options).

Comment: No luck, same error.

Comment: According https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/create-table your cache name should have a name like SQL_{SCHEMA_NAME}_{TABLE}. Could you check it? Also please provide the error log too.

Comment: Can I have multiple schema in cache?